# VirtualBox Shared Folder Not Accessible Inside Guest

Tags: virtualbox, shared-directory

I have been following this guide: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto

I am running ubuntu 16 with a Windows 2016 VM guest, the VM name is "WindowsServer2016". I need to create a shared folder that is in my home: /home/heatdeath/For_Virtual (is the name of the folder in Ubuntu that I want to share)

In virtualbox I have added the folder to the shared folder, and enabled auto-mount. Yet when I go into the Windows VM, and look under networks, there is no shared folder.

So instead of auto-mounting, I try manually by using

```
net use x: \\vboxsvr\For_Virtual
```

And I get the error:

```
System error 53 had occured
The network path was not found
```

I also tried vboxsrv.

Kinda at my wits end with this, done alot of research and nothing new turns up. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Indeed difficult & frustrating to solve, if you don't know.
My Linux distro didn't include VBoxAdditions.iso
I finally found it at http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/
under the version of virtualbox installed.

First, make sure that you belong to the vboxsf and vboxusers groups, and usb if you want to use usb access.  (It might be a bit different on your distro)

Just download the iso to a convenient location
(I use the same folder for all the msw sources),
 and select it via the cd/dvd option in virtualbox.
Then start the guest session, and in the menu at the bottom of the guest window, make sure that the iso is selected, and start it from the guest file manager.
When finished installing, select reboot.
After, all the defined shared folders appear automatically as virtual optical disks just after the virtual hard disk and the virtual optical installation disk.

BTW, I tried to get help on the virtualbox forum, just getting a rude response.
I finally found the answer with an internet search.